# I tried to uninstall Asahi Linux by removing the partition but now it just says (free space)

Tags: macos, partition, hardware

I had tried to install Asahi Linux but I got into an endless boot loop. To fix it I tried removing the partition which the script had created. I tried to refer to a few blogs but for some reason nothing was working and after a while I had this partition called (free space) of 32 GB which I could not remove or allocate.

I get the following output on running the command `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC ⁨⁩                        524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk4⁩         210.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         2.5 GB     disk0s3
   4:                        EFI ⁨EFI - ASAHI⁩             500.2 MB   disk0s4
                    (free space)                         32.1 GB    -
   5:        Apple_APFS_Recovery ⁨⁩                        5.4 GB     disk0s6

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.5 GB     disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 62.2 MB    disk2s3
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                20.5 KB    disk2s4

/dev/disk4 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +210.0 GB   disk4
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            22.0 GB    disk4s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 22.0 GB    disk4s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 853.1 MB   disk4s2
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.6 GB     disk4s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Data⁩                    99.0 GB    disk4s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      2.1 GB     disk4s6
```

As you can see I have a 32 GB volume listed as (free space) which I am unable to allocate.

Please help me and guide me through as no other tutorials and blogs worked for me.

After using the commands `diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s4` and `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s3 0`

This is my new output for `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC ⁨⁩                        524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk4⁩         210.0 GB   disk0s2
                    (free space)                         35.1 GB    -
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery ⁨⁩                        5.4 GB     disk0s6

/dev/disk4 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +210.0 GB   disk4
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            22.0 GB    disk4s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 22.0 GB    disk4s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 853.1 MB   disk4s2
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.6 GB     disk4s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Data⁩                    99.2 GB    disk4s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      2.1 GB     disk4s6
```

Comment: The  command `diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s4` would remove the hidden `EFI - ASAHI` volume. Next, the command `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s3 0` would add the free space to the `disk2` container. Do you want to keep this `disk2` container?

Comment: disk2 is the Asahi Linux stub container. It seems the OP removed the subvolumes (not the container), so that needs to be removed too. We have documentation on partitioning operations: https://github.com/AsahiLinux/docs/wiki/Partitioning-cheatsheet

Comment: @DavidAnderson I wanted to merge the disk2 with my main container can you please help me with that. Thank you as your first comment commands worked for me.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Please help me merge the disk2 with the macintosh disk

Comment: You probably should first edit your question and add the current output from `diskutil list`. At this point, I believe the commands would be `diskutil apfs deletecontainer disk0s3 MyTBD`, `diskutil erasevolume free none MyTBD` and `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have updated the question and added the new output. Can you please help me further?

Comment: Based on your new output for `diskutil list`, the command would be `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It fixed my issue!